# Can't save wordpress guttenberg custom block

Tags: wordpress, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a custom block, and I faced the issue I've never faced with before. After saving the block and realoding the page, I can see the block disabled and with a warning

> This block contains unexpected or invalid content.

And in the console I can see this:

> Block validation: Block validation failed
>
> Content generated by 'save' function:
> {here is a layout without any value from attributes}
>
> Content retrieved from post body:
> {here is a layout with all the data}

So when I log the attributes inside save function they are empty, and WP marks as an error, when the content from the save function does not match to the content posted to the server. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When registering a block in JS I forgot to add attributes with selectors. When added, block start working.

Comment: For anyone else who might come across this and find it helpful, attributes with a meta selector don't (always) appear in the save function so you get similar behaviour.